# JSON parsing not working in asp .net

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json data which is 
    [image]

after parsing using `var data = JSON.parse(value);`, it shows :

[image]

I cannot understand,what is wrong with the json parsing here?

Answer (score 0):

It does work ok.
You have an `array of objects`.

```
var data = JSON.parse(value); // array of objects
var firstObj = data[0];
console.log(firstObj.ItemId); // 153
```

Here's another example:

```
var jsonStr = '[{"ItemId":157, "Details":"first item"},{"ItemId":158, "Details":"second item"}]';
var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(json); // [Object, Object] 
for(var i = 0 ; i < json.length; i++)
{
    // Object {ItemId: 157, Details: "first item"} 
    // Object {ItemId: 158, Details: "second item"} 
    console.log(json[i]);

    //157 
    //158
    console.log(json[i].ItemId);
}
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/ffw3atfc/).

Comment: this fiddle is not showing any result to browser. http://jsfiddle.net/ffw3atfc/2/

Comment: `console.log` shows results to the console window and not to the browser. BTW you have a typo in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8t2ofpet/

Comment: in result console? lower right portion in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Each browser has it's console. If your using chrome then F12 will open the dev tools and it has a console tab.

Comment: the error showing in the console log is `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 94 of the JSON data`.   this is the curly ending brace of 1st object.